# How to add a comma and the word "and", "then" ,"or", and so on to a list in Excel or Google Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,$G3,$I3,$K3),", "," and ",MAX(1,COUNTA($G3,$I3,$K3)-1))
```

Right now the return is: `G3, I3 and K3` (the last comma before "and" is dropped)

I want it to return: `G3, I3, and K3` (with the comma & the "and" at the end)

Comment: So why don't you move it to the end?

Comment: Please see the [Help](https://superuser.com/help/) advice on [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [update](https://superuser.com/posts/1680344/edit) your question with 1) Which spreadsheet application is this about? 2) What exactly is the result you want to see (screenshot, please)? 3) What exactly is the result you currently get (screenshot, please)? [From Review](https://superuser.com/help/reviews-intro)

Comment: Without any more details, the answer (for Excel) would be `=G3 & ", " & I3 & ", and " & K3`. But somehow I suspect there's more to it than what you are showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Make one single change (addition) to your formula. Either:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,$G3,$I3,$K3)," ", ", and ",MAX(1,COUNTA($G3,$I3,$K3)-1))
```

The change is in the "what to replace" parameter of the `SUBSTITUTE()` function. You are currently having it find the last `,`  and replace it. Instead of replacing the "comma-space" with something having no comma, just use `, and`  so you replace it with your " and " but with a leading comma as well.

Or:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,$G3,$I3,$K3)," "," and ",MAX(1,COUNTA($G3,$I3,$K3)-1))
```

Same idea, pretty much. In the first one, you still replace the comma, but with a comma. Here, you don't search for and replace the comma, just that last space. So the comma stays put.

It feels like you regard the "comma-space" as being important throughout the formula, just because it is important in the single function, `TEXTJOIN()`. But Excel only cares in that function. Outside of it, you should be in the habit of shifting over to seeing it as two separate, unrelated characters that just happen to be next to each other. If the one needs not be replaced, no need to (second formula).

Sometimes, it is important to find a really unique portion of a string to anchor whatever you want to do to it. Using it to find the replacement location (the first formula) means replacing it, so it must be included in the replacement string.

The first one also feels like a fan favorite because the single change is such a teensy, tiny little ol' thing, just a wee little `,`. But the second is "more sound" I suppose, as it acts only on precisely what needs acted upon and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you the above is really helpful. One question how would you look at the =SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,$G3,$I3,$K3)," ", ", and ",MAX(1,COUNTA($G3,$I3,$K3)-1))
The logic above shows if True add ", and" to the end of the list but if the cells being looked at only has two items it should return = G3 and I3 not G3, and I3 as the logic does now